# Isobaric expansion work, W = p(V2-V1)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Isobaric process, so $W = p\Delta V$ according to my book. We have 10 kg of saturated steam at $x = 0.9$, P = 200 kPa. We add work at a rate of $700 W$ and we're interested in the time it takes.

We do work until the steam is completely vaporized. According to table:

$T_1 = 121^oC, v_f = 0.001061, v_g = 0.88578$

At $x_1=0.9$ we get $V_1 = 1 \times 0.001061 + 9 \times 0.88578 = 7.97 m^3$. $x_2 = 1$ so $V_2 = 10 \times 0.88578 = 8.8578 m^3$, which gives $\Delta V = 0.8878$.

So we have $W = p\Delta V = 200000 \times 0.8878 = 177560$

But $W = \dot W t = 700 t \Leftrightarrow t = 177560/700 = 253.7 s$

The correct answer is 3146 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your problem, you ask for the energy to vaporize $\Delta m = 1\,kg$ water at an atmospheric pressure of $200\,kPa$. ($9\,kg$ are already vaporized.)
You have to increase the internal energy $\Delta U$ of the water to vaporize it and expand the vapor against the air pressure $p\Delta V$.
The change in energy is:

$$\Delta E = \Delta U + p \Delta V$$

This is the change of the systems enthalpy $H = U + pV$ for an isobaric process:
$\Delta H_{vap} = \Delta U + p \Delta V$.

$\Delta U \approx 2025\,kJ$ at given pressure and temperature. (Look at your table.)

$p \Delta V = p \cdot (v_g - v_f)\cdot \Delta m \approx 177\,kJ$.

We get $\Delta H_{vap} = 2202\,kJ$, and you've to heat $t = 2202 /0.7\,s \approx 3146\,s$.

Answer (score -1):

The hint you have gone wrong should be that you have not used the pressure or temperature given which was given.

When the gas vaporizes the temperature will change as well as the volume.

I think you have misunderstood the meaning of the specific volumes ($v$) given. These are not the volume of 1 kg but the ratio of the volume to the mass (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_volume).

You can use the equation $$v=\frac{RT}{P}$$ to calculate the change in temperature and then $$W=nR\Delta T$$ to get the work required.

I hope this helps.